# Unexpected results when using memcpy

Tags: c, printf, memcpy

Hi i came across with this simple c program but i cant understand how this code works:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *a = "\0hey\0\0";   /*  6 */
char *b = "word\0up yo"; /* 10 */
char *c = "\0\0\0\0";    /*  4 */

int main(void)
{
    char z[20];
    char *zp = z;
    memcpy(zp, a, strlen(a)+1);
    memcpy(zp, b, strlen(b)+1);
    memcpy(zp, c, strlen(c)+1);
    /* now z contains all 20 bytes, including 8 NULLs */
    int i;

for(i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    if (z[i] == 0){
      printf("\\0");
    }

    printf("%c", z[i]);}
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting that printing z the output would be :

```
\0hey\0\0\0word\0up yo\0\0\0
```

But instead I am getting :

```
\0ord\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0???Z
```

Finally , when i print a instead of z i get the right output.
Can anyone explain to me why this happens ? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** How i could concatenate such strings?

Comment: `strlen` counts until the first `\0`. Chek your problem with that. Further, you don't concatenate the strings into `z` but overwrite it with each `memcpy`.

Comment: Print `strlen(a)`, `strlen(b)`, and `strlen(c)` to see how many bytes memcpy copies. It doesn't hurt to do even the basic debugging.

Comment: memcpy() does not append to your zp variable, it always writes from the start.,

Comment: @nos Thanks i didnt know that !

Comment: `strlen` of a is 0, b is 4, and c again 0, so you copy 1 null byte, then "word" + null byte, and again a single null byte from c to the beginning of z. Then you proceed to read both the initialized and uninitialized part of z. The latter part has unspecified value.

Comment: You only write 5 bytes of `z` , your program causes undefined behaviour when it tries to output `z[5]` and beyond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings in C are zero-terminated; the functions in the standard C library assume this property. In particular, the function `strlen` returns the number of non-zero characters from the start of the string. In your example, `strlen(a)` is equal to 0, already as the first character of `a` is zero.

The code will have the following effect:

```
 memcpy(zp, a, strlen(a)+1);
```

Now `zp` still contains `\0`, because `strlen(a)` is 0, so 1 character is copied.

```
 memcpy(zp, b, strlen(b)+1);
```

Now `zp` contains `word\0`: five characters copied.

```
 memcpy(zp, c, strlen(c)+1);
```

Now just the first character of `zp` is overwritten, so it contains `\0ord\0`.

> Finally , when i print a instead of z i get the right output. Can anyone explain to me why this happens ? Thanks in advance.

That's because `a`, `b`, and `c` happen to be allocated *sequentially* in the memory. When you print "20 bytes starting from the start of `a`", you're actually looking at the memory past the latest byte of `a`. This memory happens to contain `b`. So you actually start reading `b`. Same goes for `b` and `c`. Note that this is by no means *guaranteed*. Looking past the memory allocated for a `char *` is in fact an instance of undefined behaviour.

> How i could concatenate such strings?

In general, there is no way how to find the length of such "strings" in the runtime. I would not call them strings as such, since "string" has a specific meaning in the C language - it refers to zero terminated strings, while your's are simply regions of memory.

However, since you know the size at compile time, you can use that. To avoid magic numbers in the code, it's better to use char arrays instead of char pointers, because then you can use the `sizeof` operator. However, note that all string literals in C are implicitly zero terminated! To fit the result in the 20-byte buffer, you'll want to use `sizeof(x) - 1`:

```
char a[] = "\0hey\0\0";   /*  6 */
char b[] = "word\0up yo"; /* 10 */
char c[] = "\0\0\0\0";    /*  4 */

memcpy(zp, a, sizeof(a) - 1);
zp += sizeof(a) - 1;
memcpy(zp, b, sizeof(b) - 1);
zp += sizeof(b) - 1;
memcpy(zp, c, sizeof(c) - 1);
```